# Strange offset with Watir/Capybara and PhantomJS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to detect the location of elements on a page using Watir and PhantomJS.
My second approach using Capybara resulted in the same offset.

While the elements on the left side look good, the right side is misaligned:

[image]
I made the screenshot before and after I grab the positions for each element with `element.wd.location`, but the offset is always the same. I used `evaluate_script` and `.getBoundingClientRect()` with Capybara.

One thing looks suspicious to me: The search input field is not loaded correctly and not only shows a misalignment, but also a different size and the magnifying glass isn't shown. I don't know if this causes the offset.

I tested it with pure PhantomJS 2.1.1 (`phantomjs file.js`):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1024,
  height: 768
};

page.open('http://en.wikipedia.org/', function() {
  var positions = page.evaluate(function() {
    positions = [];
    elements = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
    for (var i=0, l=elements.length; i<l; i++) {
      pos = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect();
      positions.push(pos.left + ' ' + pos.top);
    };
    return positions;
  });

  fs.write('test.txt', positions.join("\r\n"), 'w');

  page.render('test.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Same result: If you open the *test.png*, you see the an image on the right (left: 952px, top: 259px), but the *test.txt* shows it shifted to the left (left: 891px).

Do you know what could cause this problem?

Comment: The misaligned content is aligned on the right, so the gap is likely due to the way PhantomJS is taking the screenshot. My guess is that it first resizes the viewport to the size of the the page to get a full screenshot. But this makes the scrollbar disappear, leaving more space for the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do you know what could cause this offset?**

A bug in PhantomJS v2.1.1 or in the embedded Qt WebEngine.

**Is there any workaround ?**

No.

**But I want it to work anyway, how?**

Fix it yourself or hire someone to fix it or wait for it to be fixed.

Note that the issue no longer occurs in version 2.5, but it is still in beta :

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/milestone/16
https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/

Here's a screenshot taken with phantomjs-2.5.0-beta :

[image]

Comment: PhantomJS 2.5.beta is the best solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an [issue in PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10619).

On the GitHub thread of the issue, @dantarion seems to have found a solution:

> I am running this as well.
>   My fix is to run the following on the page in an evaluate block to force PhantomJS to render at the right height viewport. It works for my use case, and while I want to see it fixed in 2.2, since its still an issue I thought I'd post here.

```
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.height = "1080px";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.maxHeight = "1080px";
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.height = "1080px";
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.maxHeight = "1080px";
```

It seems to be solving the problem. The only problem being that `background-size: cover` might still be off (as reported by @Luke-SF).

Comment: I added the styles, but got the same result.